# firebase cloud function using npm-cmd-run

Tags: android, node.js, firebase

I have a firebase project which is setup completely, RealTime Database is setup and working properly. I want to execute a cmd command in windows if a change in realtime database happens. I used npm module 'npm-cmd-run' for this, I used cloud functions of firebase to implement this.
npm-cmd-run is working fine if I run the node.js file by local server.But when uploaded it isnt working
Below is the code
Thanks in advance

```
'use strict';


const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nrc=require('node-run-cmd');


const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.run = functions.database.ref('values/volume')

    .onWrite(event => {

      const original = event.data.val();
      console.log('executing', event.params.pushId, original);

      var commands = 'nircmd mutesysvolume 1';
      //the above cmd changes volume of windows


     nrc.run(commands);//run cmd command

    event.data.ref.parent.child('commands').set(commands);
      //write command into db for reference

    });
```

[screenshot of realtime database after changing volume attritube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHmBi.png)